# Android Chrome browser is making a duplicate of every photo downloaded to my external SD card

Tags: external-sd, chrome-for-android, gallery, bugs, htc-10

Every time I download a photo (.jpg or .png file) with the Chrome browser (stable version) to my external SD card, it gets duplicated and stored also in "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures" folder (internal storage). The duplicate has always somewhat a smaller file size. How can I disable this and why is this happening ?

This doesn't happen when I download a photo with Opera Mini or MS Edge browser to my SD card for example. **It only happens to pictures downloaded with Google Chrome when the download location is set to "SD card".**

My SD card is formated as portable storage on my HTC 10 (Android Oreo).

Answer (score 0):

This answer I found on google.support and I  Copied and pasted, I'm not sure if that's okay? Or not I'm sure I will find out momentarily .

We are aware of this issue and are working on a fix for this. To resolve this immediately, you'll need to reset the permission for the Google Photos App by following the steps below. Once these steps are complete, the duplicates should disappear after a few minutes.

1. Long press the Photos App icon
2. Tap the "i" button on the top right corner to go into App info
3. Tap "Permissions"
4. Tap "Storage" under Allowed
5. Tap "Deny" and tap "Deny anyway"
6. Re-open the Photos app
7. Tap "Allow" when prompted with "Allow Photos to access photos, media, and files on your device?"
   Hope that helps....    :)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve it...just tried the Google Photos app, same problem happens when I download a photo with Chrome browser to my SD card.

Answer (score 0):

Probably happening because your **gallery is storing thumbnails of the pictures downloaded.** This is what is called cache.

To confirm, you can just see the location of one of these files. They should be in a `.thumbnails` or `thumbnails` folder, I'm not so sure.

[image: screenshot of my device showing the thumbnail folder]

In the OS I use (Lineage OS 17.1, lovin' it!), the thumbnails folder is marked by `.thumbnails` in device storage `emulated/0`. So photo and gallery apps don't index files from that folder, knowing that it's **hidden** as per the Linux convention of naming files and directories - the `.` before the `thumbnails` hides the directory.

Comment: Yes, it should be some some kind of cache, because it doesn't happen when I download pics to my external SD with other browsers, nor it happens when I just cut&paste pics from internal to SD storage...  Though I don't have a "thumbnails" folder in the Pictures folder. These duplicates show a date of 1970 when I examine them. I use the latest LeeDroid ROM on my HTC 10.

Comment: If it is cache, it's your gallery cache, not browser cache. If it's not happening with other browsers, that's because you haven't given your gallery enough time.

Comment: But it happens with Gallery GO app from Google as well. I think it has to do something with Chrome, it's weird really.

Comment: I see. I can't say.